# Image support in Terminal on windows -- How to enable/ensure it's working? (VS Code Insiders)

Tags: windows, terminal

I believe this was a recent addition and I was thrilled when I saw it: VS Code now supports sixel (and iTerm images which I don't know what it is). But the phrasing is unclear and I don't want to spend hours in trial-and-error if my environment in fact isn't supported anyway. Getting the sixels right is already computationally expensive on a personal level.

The setting "Terminal > Integrated: Enable Images" reads:
"Enables image support in the terminal, this will only work when 'Terminal > Integrated: Gpu Acceleration' is enabled. Both sixel and iTerm's inline image protocol are supported on Linux and macOS, **Windows support will light up automatically when ConPTY passes through the sequences**. Images will currently not be restored between window reloads/reconnects"

What exactly is meant by the support "lighting up"? Also are Windows Terminal sessions instances of ConPTY, and regardless of what is set as default? Will this only work on CygWin bash as before? Basically; which terminals implement ConPTY?